# Parallel.for in c# is not working

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I wrote Wpf code to generate normal distribution using random variable.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;


private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            .....


for (int t = 0; t < normalx.Count; t++)
            {
                normaly.Insert(t, (2 / ((Math.Pow(2 * Math.PI, 0.5)) * rmsnormalvalue)) * Math.Exp(-0.5 * Math.Pow(standardnormalx.ElementAt(t), 2)));
            }

...


}
```

this is sequantial codes.

To run as a parallel thread, I changed this to

```
Parallel.For(0, normalx.Count, t =>
            {
                normaly.Insert(t, (2 / ((Math.Pow(2 * Math.PI, 0.5)) * rmsnormalvalue)) * Math.Exp(-0.5 * Math.Pow(standardnormalx.ElementAt(t), 2)));
            });
```

but build is ok, but in run-time only one thread region(`normalx.Count/8` <- my pc is i7)

was worked and compuated.

What's the wrong?

Comment: What is `normaly` and is it thread-safe ?

Answer (score 2):

The TPL does not guarantee that it will use a given number of threads for a parallel loop.  It is ABLE to, but it may determine that the overhead of starting additional threads is too much given the amount of work to be done within the loop and just run on a single thread.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx

> Executes a for loop in which iterations *may* run in parallel.

(emphasis mine)

You *may* be able to force multiple threads (not that forcing is necessarily a good idea) by providing a custom partitioner, but I have not tried that yet

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560853.aspx

The TPL is still free to say "nice that you provided a custom partitioner, but I'm still going to execute each partition sequentially on one thread".  I don't know how the current implementation behaves in that regard.

**UPDATE**

Re-reading and checking Henk's comment, I'm not sure I read your question correctly the first time.

Are you saying that only some of the normals have been computed?   If that is the case, it could be because whatever collection is backing `normaly` is not thread-safe.

If that is the case, you could do your calculation, assign it to a temporary variable, then use a `lock` around the actual insert.  That would create a bottleneck inserting into the collection, but you would still gain parallelism for the calculation.

Comment: Would that change the region of the input/output?

Comment: @Henk: I may have misunderstood the question.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certainly the case that `normaly.Insert(t, ...)` is not thread-safe, nor is it likely to be the operation you want to perform. What you want to do is create a blank datastructure ahead of time with all the slots you'll need, then fill them in with your parallel loop. Here's how you might do it:

```
var temp = new double[normalx.Count];
Parallel.For(0, normalx.Count, t =>
    temp[t] = 2 / ((Math.Pow(2 * Math.PI, 0.5)) * rmsnormalvalue)) *
              Math.Exp(-0.5 * Math.Pow(standardnormalx.ElementAt(t), 2));
normaly = temp.ToList();
```